# How to stop click propagation when clicking checkbox in jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, radio-button

In my jquery mobile app, I add a row to a listview, and the entire row has a click event which changes the page. In the row there is many columns and one of the columns is a checkbox. This is how I initialize it after dynamically adding to the DOM listview.

```
    var checkBoxes = $(context).find("#search-table").find(".custom-radio");

    checkBoxes.checkboxradio().prop("checked", false).checkboxradio( "refresh" );

    checkBoxes.parent().click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        //return false;
    });
```

The problem is that if I click the checkbox, then it triggers the row click event. I want it so that it does not do that. Whatever I try doesn't work. Results were like if I click the checkbox, it doesn't even change state, but the row click doesn't trigger.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Something along these lines? http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/duyxtt9c/

Comment: your code worked. I think the problem was because I was using `.click(function` instead of `).on("click"` which I think was messing my event propagation stuff.